# Comparing 12hour format time

Tags: c++

I have to calculate which time occurs first in the day.
Input format is like 12:48AM.

Here is my comparison function.

```
string timeCompare(string t1, string t2)
{
    if(t1[5] == 'A' && t1[6]== 'M' && t2[5]=='P')
    {
        return "First";
    }
    else if (t2[5] == 'A' && t2[6] == 'M' && t1[5]=='P')
    {
        return "Second";
    }
    else if (t2[5] == 'A' && t2[6] == 'M' && t1[5]=='A' && t1[6]=='M' )
    {  
        if(stoi(t1)<stoi(t2))
        {
            return "First";
        }
        else if(stoi(t2) == stoi(t1))
        {
            if(t2[3] > t2[3])
            {
                return "Second";
            }
            else if(t2[3] < t1[3])
            {
                return "First";
            }
            else if(t2[3] == t1[3])
            {
                if(t2[4] > t1[4])
                {
                    return "First";
                } 
                if(t1[4] > t2[4])
                {
                    return "First";
                }
                else 
                {
                    return "Equal";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is generic and is giving correct output of all times. 
**But since this code is pretty lengthy and contains a lot of comparisons, is there anyway I can shorten this code?**

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also please note that questions about improving *working code* belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It would be a better idea to use actual time types, which have operators for comparison, and save the string representations for display only. Also, your string return values are error prone, as for example the return 0; at the end. If you use strings, at least define constants for "First", etc.

Comment: Are you sure this gives "correct output of all times"?  What about two different PM times?  Or when only one of the times has 12 for the hour and they're both AM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd convert them to integers (count of minutes), and compare:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int timeToInt(const string& t) {
  int hr=stoi(t, nullptr) % 12;
  int min=stoi(t.substr(3),nullptr);

  int time=hr*60+min;

  if (t.at(5)=='p' || t.at(5)=='P') {
    time+=12*60;
  }
  return time;
}

string timeCompare(const string& t1, const string& t2){
  int time1=timeToInt(t1);
  int time2=timeToInt(t2);
  if (time1<time2) {
    return "First";
  } else {
    return "Second";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the format is always like `09:35AM` and not like `9:35AM`, then the following code should work, too. Note that the 5th character is the most significant distinction, and we can make use of the fact that `'A' < 'M'`. If this position is equal for both `t1` and `t2`, then a simple lexographical comparison should do:

```
string timeCompare(string t1, string t2){
  if(t1[5] < t2[5])
    return "First";
  else if(t1[5] > t2[5])
    return "Second";
  else
    return (t1 < t2) ? "First" : "Second";
}
```

And if you change the signature of your function to return a boolean, then the code could be even shorter written as follows:

```
bool time1LessThanTime2(string t1, string t2){
  return (t1[5] == t2[5]) ? (t1 < t2) : (t1[5] < t2[5]);
}
```

Comment: What about "12:00AM" and "01:00AM"?

Comment: Also, this doesn't account for the "Equal" case from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

For such thins use standard library:

```
std::time_t stringToTimeT(const string& s1)
{
    struct std::tm tm {};
    static const auto timeFormat = "%I:%M%p";
    if ((std::istringstream(s1) >> std::get_time(&tm, timeFormat)).eof())
    {
        return mktime(&tm);
    }
    throw std::logic_error("Failed to parse time: "s + s1);
}

double diffTimeFromStrings(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    return difftime(stringToTimeT(s1), stringToTimeT(s2));
}
```

Disclaimer: I did some testing and it turns out that "%p" doesn't work as [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time). All other format parameters are working fine.
Here is an [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U9EvPZD7vm1cUhNN).